# AttributeError when reading data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to code logistic regression from scratch using the wisconsin breast cancer dataset but keep getting an attribute error

```
'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'target'
```

in `Y = data.target`, for which I can't find the solution:

```
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\Hannah\Desktop\Research Project\data.csv",header=0)
X = data.values[:, :30] 
Y = data.target['diagnosis']
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you are using `pandas` to read csv and want to assign values in column `diagnosis` to variable `Y`. In this case you no need `target`. DataFrame have not the property at all, according error. Just `data['diagnosis']` should return what you need.